# How to block a checkbox to be checked in on a Checked event when some condition is not met?

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox

I'm using `System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox`. I am implement the `OnChecked` event handler, I want the checkbox to be unchecked if some condition is not met after the handler runs, how should I implement the handler?

xaml code:

```
<CheckBox  Checked="OnChecked" >Checkbox text</CheckBox>
```

C# code:

```
private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Block checkbox being checked if some condition not met
}
```

Comment: why don't you run the checkbox as disabled, and onCoditionMetEvent enable it!

Comment: That also gives the user a visual cue that they can't check it.

Comment: Really bad UX. Don't build an app that lets people do things then immediately "corrects" their actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OnChecked event handler, you can add an if block to check if your conditions have met. If the condition is not satisfied, you can clear the [IsChecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox(v=vs.105).aspx) property.

```
private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (true) // your condition
    {
        ((CheckBox) sender).IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if(*your condition*)
     {
          (sender as System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox).IsChecked = false;
     }
}
```